# IllegalArgumentException - getter method of property: id using HQL IN clause

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I have the following HQL (simplified to show the error):

```
Skill.findAll("from Skill as skill where skill in(:skills)",[skills:skills])
```

where `skills` is a list of skills.

When executed it generates this error:

```
property.BasicPropertyAccessor - IllegalArgumentException in class: 
core.Skill, getter method of property: id
```

But if I use this HQL it works fine:

```
Skill.findAll("from Skill as skill where skill.id in(:skills)",[skills:skills*.id])
```

What can be wrong with the first one? (I'm using Grails 2.3.7)

Comment: Is using hql required? You can use grails where mechanism or hibernate criteria

Comment: It's not required because I am adapting old code and I can modify it but I'm curious why it doesn't work.